# TFS Run Shell doesn't work: Not found bash: null

Tags: bash, team-foundation-server

Im trying to run a bash script in the Release in TFS 2015. For these im using the "Shell Script" - Job.

Content:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Start SSH"

ssh user@ip << EOF
    echo "Unzip"
    unzip -o -d A B.zip
    rm B.zip
    cp -r A/. B
    rm -rf A
    echo "Finished"
EOF
```

I've tried the Script on my bash and ist works correctly, but on running the release i've got:

> 2018-08-29T09:04:08.7988672Z Starting task: Shell Script
>   $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Build
>   Magento/magento/scripts/build.sh   2018-08-29T09:04:08.7988672Z Set
>   workingFolder to default: D:\AgentA\tasks\ShellScript\1.0.17
>   2018-08-29T09:04:08.9863750Z ##[debug]check path :
>   D:\AgentA\tasks\ShellScript\1.0.17\task.json
>   2018-08-29T09:04:08.9863750Z ##[debug]set resource file to:
>   D:\AgentA\tasks\ShellScript\1.0.17\task.json
>   2018-08-29T09:04:08.9863750Z ##[debug]system.culture=en-US
>   2018-08-29T09:04:08.9863750Z ##[debug]load strings from:
>   D:\AgentA\tasks\ShellScript\1.0.17\task.json
>   2018-08-29T09:04:08.9863750Z ##[debug]load loc strings from:
>   D:\AgentA\tasks\ShellScript\1.0.17\Strings\resources.resjson\en-US\resources.resjson
>   2018-08-29T09:04:08.9863750Z ##[debug]check path : null
>   2018-08-29T09:04:08.9863750Z ##[debug]load strings from:
>   D:\AgentA\tasks\ShellScript\1.0.17\node_modules\vsts-task-lib\lib.json
>   2018-08-29T09:04:08.9863750Z ##[debug]load loc strings from:
>   D:\AgentA\tasks\ShellScript\1.0.17\node_modules\vsts-task-lib\Strings\resources.resjson\en-US\resources.resjson
>   2018-08-29T09:04:08.9863750Z ##[debug]task result: Failed
>   2018-08-29T09:04:08.9863750Z Not found bash: null
>   2018-08-29T09:04:09.0019981Z Finishing task: ShellScript
>   2018-08-29T09:04:09.0176245Z ##[error]Task ShellScript failed. This
>   caused the job to fail. Look at the logs for the task for more
>   details.

Is eventually the Bash not on TFS 2015?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, i have a Workaround. I am using Plink in CommandLine-Job. The Job calls Plink and Plink connects to the target and runs the specified commands. The Plink.exe must be on the TFS.